# Why don’t we skip pesukim of comfort in Eichah?

Tags: tisha-bav, lamentations-eicha

The Shulchan Aruch rules (OC 554:1) that one may learn the sad parts of Yirmiya, provided that he skip the comforting parts.

Yet, there are several pesukim in Eichah that discuss comfort (ex. 4:22 - “Your sin has been expiated, daughter of Zion; you will not be exiled again”). Why, when we read Eichah publicly on Tishah B’Av, are we not enjoined to skip these verses as well, the same way we are enjoined to skip such verses in Yirmiya?

Comment: There's bits of comforting stuff throughout the Kinnot too. Even at the end of Nachem there's a comfort verse. (Seemingly small bits are ok.)

Answer (score -1):

Part of Tisha B'Av is recognizing that only after we are sent to exile can the redemption occur.  As our Sages state, Moshiach ben Dovid is "born on Tisha B'Av" (Beraishis Rabbah on 1:2).  Part of the day is connecting both to the past and the future.  The book of Eicha expresses this as a primary source and therefore we read both parts.  They are united as one in the book.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question whatsoever. According to your logic, this should be true across the board, not just regarding Eichah. Yirmiya is also a primary source, yet we have to skip the comforting parts in there. (Just to nitpick - “we” read this? Only Ashkenazim read Eichah on Tishah B’Av.)

Comment: Just to clarify my previous comment: I didn’t ask why we don’t skip the comforting parts of Eichah. I asked why Eichah and Yirmiya are different, and you don’t address that whatsoever.

Comment: @DonielF You didn't? Then maybe you should rephrase "Why, when we read Eichah... are we not enjoined to skip these verses as well?" (The contrasting "as well" is too subtle.)

Comment: Apologies, I used"we" because you used "we". You didn't ask for more sources but look in Masechet Soferim 18:4-5 and the Ramban over there for our Sages answer. I also suggest that if you are sincerely asking questions that you ask for clarification when you don't agree with an answer rather than berate those that would help you. Or you ask your Rebbi in person so as to have Yirash Shomayim in your response.

Comment: @Jon Could you point to where exactly "the Ramban over there" is?

Comment: @Jon I apologize if my comment came across as berating. I did not intend at all for it to come across that way.

Comment: @DonielF "Only Ashkenazim read Eichah on Tishah B’Av" this is not true

Comment: @wfb What other communities read it? As far as I’m aware Sefardim read Iyov instead. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @DonielF Yes, see Shulchan Aruch OC 559

Comment: Torat Ha'Adam (Chavel ed. Pg. 258)  For Ramban.  @DonielF no worries brother tizku lemitzvos!